# TFS 2010 API Documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-sdk

So after countless hours crawling the internet I am unable to find any form of proper API for TFS 2010 for C# (I have not installed any SPs yet) I am unable to find any proper results

I have found the SDK on the Microsoft site but it is for Java for some reason.. Can anyone help me and provide me with some proper documentation, I have found some relating to VS2005 but this all seems to have been removed from the framework as you can no longer import Microsoft.Core

Links to items I have looked at:

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616
- http://tfsapiwrapper.codeplex.com/ (although this is kind of what I need, I don't hugely want to install random wrappers without a huge amount of information regarding it)

Comment: Could you provide detail on what you want to do? API in the context of a service is a bit vague. For instance are you looking to customize the server or client, or automate certain activities?

Comment: I am in the process of writing a console application that will have the ability to grab a projects name based on some data within our CSProj files, search our TFS server for a matching project, then record changesets which have been added since the date of the last release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a C# API (likely, based on the question tags), there is the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation` namespace. I have used it before.

You will need to include the following assemblies as references in your project:

- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client`
- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common`

And one or more of the following based on your specific needs:

- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client`
- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client`
- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client`
- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client`

Comment: Please read the OP and note that I can not use this for some reason.

Comment: Why are you unable to use it? These are not the Java APIs you referred to in the OP.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the Assemblies

Comment: If they are unavailable in the references tab, you may want to check the version/flavor of .NET framework the project is using. I have used these with success in VS2010 to connect to TFS2010.

Comment: I was missing the assemblies *facepalms*

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252473.aspx#ObMod
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff732845.aspx

All are in .NET

I did not even know there was a Java API...

Comment: I found it crazy that there was a Java API

Comment: @HelloWorld: this is our cross-platform API.